# Additional left margin using enumerate

Tags: margins, enumerate, enumitem

Does a code like `leftmargin=* plus 2.5ex` exist?
I want to move the whole list to the right.

[image]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
bibliography=totoc,
toc=listof,
captions=tableheading,
listof=entryprefix,
]
{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     
\usepackage{textcomp}                           
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}      
\usepackage{lmodern}                            
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                   
\usepackage{microtype}                          
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
%%
\begin{enumerate}[label=These \emph{\normalfont \arabic*}),partopsep=2.5ex, itemsep=0.75ex, leftmargin=*, rightmargin=2.5ex]
\item Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\item Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just make the `labelindent` 2.5ex? (Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, as suggested by @Alan Munn?

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
bibliography=totoc,
toc=listof,
captions=tableheading,
listof=entryprefix,
]
{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
%%
\begin{enumerate}[label=These \emph{\normalfont\arabic*}), labelindent=2.5ex, partopsep=2.5ex, itemsep=0.75ex, leftmargin=*, rightmargin=2.5ex]
\item Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\item Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et, tellus.
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have the overview of all the options in front of me … :S It was the solution!

Comment: Oddly enough the posted code doesn't actually include the solution.

Comment: @AlanMunn: A problem with my clipboard manager, as happens from time to time, and I don't always check. 'Tis fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!